# cannot use regular expression to search in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to index text, word files and also search some content in these files. It is OK when I search for a specific string but when I try to use a regular expression to search, it will not work any more. In the following, I will list some crucial code for explaining.

**The index function:**

```
    // FileBean is the class contains the file path,
    // file content, file lastModified information
    public void indexDoc(IndexWriter writer, FileBean t) throws Exception {
    Document doc = new Document();
    System.out.println(t.getPath());
    doc.add(new StringField(LuceneConstants.PATH, t.getPath(), Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new LongPoint(LuceneConstants.MODIFIED, t.getModified()));
    doc.add(new TextField(LuceneConstants.CONTENT, t.getContent(), Field.Store.NO));
    if (writer.getConfig().getOpenMode() == IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE){
        writer.addDocument(doc);
    } else{
        writer.updateDocument(new Term(LuceneConstants.PATH, t.getPath()), doc);
    }
}
```

I am using queryParse to build the query, the query will be a RegexQuery just like '\d{16}' for a number.

**the search function**

```
    public static TopDocs getResults(IndexSearcher searcher, Query query) throws IOException {
    TopDocs docs = searcher.search(query, 10);
    return docs;
}
```

TopDocs's totalHit is 0, which is not what I expect. It seems to me that there is no file being searched. This content should satisfy with the given regular expression that is provided.

I tried googling it but still I have not found a valid solution. Can anyone provide any suggestions on why totalHit is returning 0? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, I finally found the reason. Though I didn't know what was the deep reason. I found if I used '[0-9]' instead if '\d'. It would be OK!!!!!
If anyone could explain this, it will be wonderful!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try taking away the '+', so it would be '\d{16}'.

Comment: sorry, I paste wrong. The code is just /\d{16}/. The regular is OK.